# Processing: replace space with non-breaking space

Tags: char, processing, space

I keep getting an error of "Badly formed character constant" when using this code in Processing 1.5.1. I want to replace all spaces with non-breaking spaces in my String. Any help would be appreciated.

```java
    String newStr;
    String S = "Hello there world"
    char c = '\u00A0';
    newStr = S.replace(' ', c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Processing indicates unicode without quotes and with the prefix 0x
Try this:

```
String newStr;
String S = "Hello there world"
char c = 0x00A0;
newStr = S.replace(' ', c);
```